# Rails Cache Digest and Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using Jbuilder for my JSON API output and now i want to add caching using the 'cache_digest' gem for Rails 3.2.13.

It works fine, the cache template is created and it read from the cache but the problem is, if i change a model entry, like changing the "title", it does not expire the cache and it still shows the old title.

This is my jbuilder template index:

```
json.cache! "news" do |json|
    json.array!(@news) do |news|
        json.id news.id
        json.title news.title
        json.excerpt news.excerpt
        json.content strip_links news.content
        json.image news.image
        json.source news.source
        json.published_at news.published_at
        json.created_at news.created_at
    end
end
```

I am changing attributes via the RailsAdmin interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to pass the @news collection instead of a "news" string as the cache key, like:

```
json.cache! @news do |json|
    json.array!(@news) do |news|
        json.id news.id
        json.title news.title
        json.excerpt news.excerpt
        json.content strip_links news.content
        json.image news.image
        json.source news.source
        json.published_at news.published_at
        json.created_at news.created_at
    end
end
```

When i first tried this i got an error saying "Filename too long" when it tried to create the cache file on disk. This was because my @news collection was too big (too many objects) so i changed it to return fewer objects. This would not be a problem with things like memcached but when saving to disk the filename's length is constrained by the operating system.